# show data in android using gridview from database

Tags: android, gridview, android-widget

I want to display data, from a database, in a gridview.
Means I have a data in my table (let it's a customer detail) and I want to show it in gridview (or any other control to display details) same as we done in asp.net.

**Solution:--**

```
public void FillGrid() {
    DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    dbh.openDataBase();
    Cursor cursor;
    GridView grv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grvData);
    cursor = dbh.getGridData();
    dbh.close();
    if (cursor != null) {
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.gridlayout, cursor,
                new String[] { GridTestActivity.KEY_ROW_ID, GridTestActivity.KEY_ID, GridTestActivity.KEY_DESCRIPTION } 
                ,new int[] { R.id.txtGrv_id, R.id.txtGrvid, R.id.txtGrvDescription } );
        adapter.setViewResource(R.layout.gridlayout);
        grv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to emulate a classic data aware grid, with well defined columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [full example](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Also if your beginning Android [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224193) would be a good book for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post for gridview: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

and this for cursor adapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you pls be a little more descriptive?

Comment: Let its a detail of customers which i have to show in android mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You can Set the GridView With 3 Columns. It will give you a look of Table form.

OR

You can use customized GridView for your application Using the Following type of Codes..

**customergrid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="357dp"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And, for each Row use a customized Xml file..

**customerrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TableRow>
<TextView
 android:layout_width="50px"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/row_ID"
 android:padding="5px"
 android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView 
 android:layout_width="50px"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/key_ID"
 android:padding="5px"
 android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView 
 android:layout_width="50px"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/key_Description"
 android:padding="5px"
 android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Use customergrid.xml on the Oncreate() method and use customerrow.xml in the Grid creation like as your code..

```
public void FillGrid() {
DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
dbh.openDataBase();
Cursor cursor;
GridView grv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grvData);
cursor = dbh.getGridData();
dbh.close();
if (cursor != null) {
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.customerrow, cursor, new String[] { GridTestActivity.KEY_ROW_ID,
            GridTestActivity.KEY_ID, GridTestActivity.KEY_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
            R.id.txtGrv_id, R.id.txtGrvid, R.id.txtGrvDescription } );
    adapter.setViewResource(R.layout.gridlayout);
    grv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

You can get the data from the Database on the gridview now.

Comment: Post your full project code for the Detailed Discussion, It may help for me.. I too developing a task for getting data on a Grid view from DB and Updating using an Alert box. I struck in my Process, if you have any idea share it..