# How to fill a gridview/listview with data from an ACCESS database in Android?

Tags: android, database, listview, ms-access, gridview

I'm starting my first android app and (for now) i need it just to do this: load a gridview or listview (dont know which is best) with data from an Access database that i created.

I tried to search around ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269600/show-data-in-android-using-gridview-from-database)) but i just found how to CREATE new tables when the app opens, and that doesn't fit my needs.
To anyone who can help me, i apreciate it!

Thanks for reading.

[EDIT]
Ok, i discovered that i can't use an access database on my app, oh well.

Comment: Do you want to ship your app with a pre-filled database?

Comment: Basically, yes. But i needed it to be in access, not in sqlite. anyway, I might dont need to work on this (for now).

Comment: Android works with SQLite, not Access. Note that SQLite can be used in VB.NET/C# as well. And also in Objective C (iOS).